# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context') in spfx

Tags: spfx, error, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

[image]

When I am checking my published document that time I am facing this problem, before this it was running fine.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript TypeError is thrown when an operand or argument passed to a function is incompatible with the type expected by that operator or function. This error occurs in Chrome Browser when you read a property or call a method on an undefined object .

Regards,
Peter